# any example of ofVideoPlayer on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, openframeworks

Anyone knows any example of ofVideoPlayer working on iPhone??

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20) library - they have a sample Youtube player there.

Comment: There's no video component inside this library, but I'll keep the link. Thanks!